# how can i check user_id of an item is equal to auth.id [Firebase]

Tags: foreign-keys, firebase, rules, userid

I want to "link" items to users in my firebase db and i want to create some good rules to check if user is allow to write:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.id == $userid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.id == $userid"
      }
    },
    "items": {
      "$itemid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.id == root.child('items').child($itemid).child('user_id').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance ! ;)

Comment: I found the thing: `".write": "auth != null && data.child('user_id').val() + '' == auth.id"`